# Which library should be used to Jboss AMQ connection using JMS

Tags: jboss-amq

According to Jboss AMQ guide, AMQ JMS Client 1.1.0 is should be used to connect to broker. But it works only with amqp:// or amqps:// not with tcp:// or ssl:// .
Which library we should use for non-amqp but standard JMS connection?

Official sample programs use maven and redhat repo for required library and it is not using AMQ JMS Client 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no such thing as a "standard JMS connection" because the JMS specification only describes an API and not any kind of wire-level format or connection mechanism.  Such details are left up to the implementation.

Is there a specific problem with using AMQP as the protocol even though the client itself fully implements the JMS API?

Comment: Thanks Justin. Problem is: connection URL preceding with tcp:// or ssl://. Basically in AMQP, certificate login is not supported.

Comment: Which version of AMQ are you using?

Comment: I am using 7.0.1

Comment: In that case you can use the "core" JMS client (it uses the Artemis "core" protocol rather than AMQP).  Take a look at any of the examples that ship with AMQ 7 for a demonstration of how to use it.  To be clear, "ssl://" is not specifically supported.  You'd need to use something like tcp://<host>:<port>?sslEnabled=true to get SSL functionality.